# Custom paging in a gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, custompaging

I want to make a custom paging for my gridview in asp.net 'cause i have a lot of information in my database. My problem is when i generate linkbuttons. I put them in a panel, but i have more than 7000 buttons for my pages. When i add them into my panel, it displays me all of them on 10 lines in my page. I need to display only 10 and when i press the last of them to display other 10 buttons.
My code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < nrPages; index++)
                {
                    int pageNo = index + 1;
                    LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                    lnk.Click += new EventHandler(PageChange);

                    lnk.ID = "PageLink" + pageNo.ToString();
                    lnk.CommandName = "Page";
                    lnk.Text = " " + pageNo.ToString() + " ";
                    lnk.CommandArgument = index.ToString();

                    PanelPager.Controls.Add(lnk);
                }

public void PageChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int pageIndex = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
            object dataSource = GetDataSource(OwnerId, null, pageIndex);
            PushData(dataSource);

        }
```

Here i use my linkButton

Comment: Simply you are doing pagination of page numbers so the logic would be the same pagination as you are doing pagination of your actual data.

Comment: Keep in mind that all 70.000+ rows are still retrieved from database/viewstate every time the GridView is loaded. That means A LOT of extra traffic for displaying just 10 rows. Start using Ajax to retrieve the page datasets.

Comment: @VDWWD. no there are not retrived every time.I use ROW_NUM() in my Sql server, and i load only between page index and page size

Answer (score 0):

```
int nrPages = 7000;

public void RenderPageNumbers(int nextPageNo)
{
    int pageSize = 10;
    int totalPages = nrPages / pageSize;
    var startIndex = ((nextPageNo -1) * pageSize ) + 1
    for (int index = startIndex; index < startIndex + pageSize; index++)
    {
        int pageNo = index;
        LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
        lnk.Click += new EventHandler(PageChange);

        lnk.ID = "PageLink" + pageNo.ToString();
        lnk.CommandName = "Page";
        lnk.Text = " " + pageNo.ToString() + " ";
        lnk.CommandArgument = index.ToString();

        PanelPager.Controls.Add(lnk);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting commandArgument of link? How are you planning to use it?

Comment: look at my edit, i use to know the index page and bring from database only some rows

Comment: Got it...... that link will be used to switch the datapage, right? then you don't use it for what I say... apologies..

Comment: What I meant was to call this method from last button of the page numbers so that it will render the next 10 page numbers.

Comment: np, any other idea?

Comment: Can you explain how are you using it? We can have this conversation as chat if you want.